# C# MVC Site Forcing Users to Re-authenticate

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, forms-authentication

I have a website written with the C# MVC 3 framework using Forms authentication.  The site allows anonymous viewing for most of its content but has a directory containing PDF documents that require users to be authenticated to view.

This works nearly all the time but occasionally an authenticated user will have a problem.  When they click on a document they repeatedly get redirected to the login screen, forcing them to re-authenticate.  Once they do they are then redirected to the document.  Not a complete disaster but still annoying for users.  Another scenario would be an authenticated user opening one of the PDF document just fine, but if they click on a link in that document that redirects them to another PDF document in the same directory, the system will then force them to re-authenticate.

I first thought this may be a browser/cookie issue but from what I can gather by talking to users with this problem, it can happen with Firefox or IE, and with history/cookies enabled. Months ago I too experienced the problem in a hotel using their public WI-FI, but I've never experienced it at work using my office connection or at home.

The website allows anonymous user access but the directory where the PDF documents reside contains the following web.config file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
   <system.web>
      <authentication>
         <deny users=”?” />
      </authentication>
   </system.web>
</configuration>
```

I am completely stumped as to what may be going on with these users.  Any ideas would be extremely helpful.

Comment: You might start by reading this post: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BackToBasicsDynamicImageGenerationASPNETControllersRoutingIHttpHandlersAndRunAllManagedModulesForAllRequests.aspx

Comment: Craig, thanks for the advice.  I read the article but unless I'm missing something, the PDF files seem to be getting handled fine except for the additional step some users experience which is having to re-authenticate before viewing them.  The article also seemed to focus on dynamically created files, where my content is completely static.  If there's something I missed I'd be grateful for any insight you could provide.

Comment: You're in MVC but you have a web.config set to deny anonymous users? MVC typically uses the `[Authorize]` attribute on the Controller actions. I would delete that config file.

Answer (score 0):

Is the application deployed in a farm?
I've seen intermittent issues like this, when one of the nodes doesn't have the same MachineKey as the rest.